# tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent' automatically getting undone

Tags: tinymce

When I am adding some text with tinyMCE.execCommand it appears for couple of seconds and then automatically undoes.

Trying to understand how the undo level works.
How to add undo/manage level?

Striped down version of code used:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TinyMCE editor</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var toolbar =
                "fontselect,fontsizeselect, formatselect, bold,italic,underline,|," +
                "forecolor,backcolor,|,removeformat,cleanup,|,codemirror2,charmap,|,fullscreen";

        var toolbar2 =
                "undo,redo,|,pastetext,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|," +
                "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,anchor,image";

        var initHtmlMode = {
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advanced",
            theme_advanced_buttons1: toolbar,
            theme_advanced_buttons2: toolbar2,
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing: true
        };

        tinyMCE.init(initHtmlMode);

        function showList() {
            tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'some text');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <textarea id="content" rows="15" style="width: 80%"></textarea>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="showList()">Insert</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onclick() was refreshing the page

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

Fixed it.